# JavaScript HTMLCollection - element[0].children[0] returns undefined, element[0].children returns HTMLCollection[3]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a AngularJS directive that removes DOM nodes and replaces them with similar nodes. To prevent me having to manually remove text nodes I use the HTML DOM `children` Property rather than `childNodes`. When I output the following, `console.log(element[0].children);` I get the following in my Dev Tools:

```
children: HTMLCollection[3]
0: div.visitors-list.col-xs-3.u-height-100
1: div.col-xs-6.profile-wrapper.u-height-100
2: div.visitors-list.col-xs-3.u-height-100
length: 3
```

However when I try to explicitly reference a Node, like so `console.log(element[0].children[0]);` I get `undefined`. I assume it is impossible to reference the collection explicitly as it is not an actual array and I would have to use the .call method from the array prototype, for example `[].forEach.call` Do I need to use `[].forEach.call` on the HTMLCollection or is my reference `element[0].children[0]` just incorrect? Any advice is appreciated.

I have attached a sample jsbin to show how I try to add a new css class to a child node: https://jsbin.com/poqaqa/edit?html,console,output

However my fiddle works!

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. you can always fetch element from HTMLCollection. If you can create plnkr. It will be great help for others

Comment: Please do a `console.log(element[0].children.length)`

Comment: I'm just putting a fiddle together...

Comment: Fiddle is here: https://jsbin.com/poqaqa/edit?html,console,output

Comment: @Bergi - console.log(element[0].children.length) outputs '1', something strange is happening here... especially as my jsbin works as I want!

Comment: I think I have an answer... I should be using element[0].children[0].children[1] my HTML structure... wasn't what I thought it was!